# SpecFlow on .net core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, specflow

I need to install nuget package SpecFlow 2.1.0 on .net core 2.0 project but i get issue.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Allow me suggest an alternative - [Xunit.Gherkin.Quick](https://github.com/ttutisani/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick). I wrote it when I discovered that SpecFlow is not compatible with .NET Core, and I needed to do Gherkin based BDD tests in .NET Core with Xunit.

Besides being compatible with .NET Core and regular .NET too (since it's a .NET Standard library), it works almost like specflow:

- Supports feature files with Gherkin language in it.
- gives you Given/When/Then etc. attributes to implement scenario steps.

What it does not do, compared to SpecFlow:

- It does not automatically generate empty Given/When/Then etc. methods for you based on feature file. Instead, you need to derive from Feature base class and write scenario steps manually. (*I think not a big deal to manually write a method signature with attribute on it*)
- It only supports Xunit and no other test frameworks.

Acceptable compromise in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

From [Their website:](http://specflow.org/documentation/.NET-Support/)

> .NET Core is not yet supported, but we are working on it.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [preview version of SpecFlow 3](https://specflow.org/2018/specflow-3-public-preview-now-available/) available with support for .NET Core.

Comment: And SpecFlow 3 is already released: https://specflow.org/2018/net-core-support-specflow/

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow 3 supports .NET Core: [SpecFlow 3](https://specflow.org/2019/specflow-3-is-here/)

Answer (score 1):

From [Their website](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.NetCore/):

> Generate tests from SpecFlow feature files inside .NET Core projects.

Insert this command in Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package SpecFlow.NetCore -Version 1.3.2
```